# JDT weaving is currently disabled

Tags: scala, eclipse-jdt, scala-ide

I just installed Eclipse standard 4.4 Luna, and after installing the Scala IDE and friends I get

```
JDT Weaving is currently disabled. The Scala IDE needs JDT Weaving to be active,
or it will not work correctly. 

Activate JDT Weaving and Restart Eclipse? (Highly Recommended)

[OK] [Cancel]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Now my comments on this error message

- In general error messages that tell you what to do, but not how to do it are frustrating.
- The [OK] button implies that the dialog will enable it for me, but it does exactly the same as clicking the [Cancel] button. Consequently, the UI design is defective.
- The preferences dialog in Luna does not show anything under JDT or Weaving.
- The help search in Luna for "JTD Weaving" returns too much information to offer any simple solution.
- My search via Google turns up interesting discussion on the problem, but fails to simply state the solution, or if there is one.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-ide-user/7GdTuQHyP4Q/aiUt70lnzigJ

Comment: Which version of the Scala IDE did you install? This one is advertised as Luna compatible and seems to work for me: http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html#scala-ide-400-milestone-2

Comment: There's a issue in STS [1] that points to a regression in Eclipse [2], that is claimed to be fixed in the Integration builds for 4.4. I, however, am still seeing this problem.
[1] https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3762
[2] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432670

Comment: Thanks @Paul, using http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/dev/site seems to get around the JDT Weaving problem, but now I am having other problems getting my Scala projects to port forward from Kepler to Luna. Ces't la vie

Comment: Originally I used the Scala IDE from Eclipse Marketplace. I guess it takes a while for the marketplace to get updated with the correct versions of things.

Comment: OK, all good now, able to compile and run 2.10 code with 2.11, Luna and Lithium.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem with Eclipse Luna. Your problem might be due to installing the plugin for wrong version of Eclipse.

Did you install Scala plugin from this page: [Download the 3.0 Release of the Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html)? It is for Juno and Kepler only.

I downloaded the plugin from the link at [Download the Latest Nightly Build](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html), using http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-scala-ide-luna-211x. And it works perfectly now.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem, and similar to the answer above, I solved it by updating scala-ide.  The nightly build site didn't have updated plugins.  The latest milestone release, however, had everything I needed.  You can find the latest milestone releases here:

http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html

And the version I am using which is working for me today (and advertised to be working well on Luna) is:
http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/dev/site/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve it by installing fresh copy of Eclipse Luna with the latest Scala IDE plugin. Now JDT option is enabled and read only.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse 4.4 use this update site for the Scala plugin:

http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/stable/site

This one works for me in Eclipse 4.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but problem wasn't with version of scala plugin but with the name of directory of eclipse. One of the folders had '!' sign in the name and it made it imposible to enable jdt weaving. When I installed eclipse in another directory with normal signs everything runs ok.